# Integration test instead of unit test

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

let's assume I have a custom collection object. How can I create a unit test (with no dependencies) for the remove method? I have to call the add method first to be able to remove that item afterwards and therefore the remove method has a dependency to the add method. In most cases this custom collection class will have a protected property which includes all added collection items. Therefore I can't mock the add method because then I have no collection items to remove.

```
class Item 
{
    private $identifier;

    public function __construct($identifier)
    {
        $this->identifier = $identifier;
    }

    public function getIdentifier() { return $this->identifier; }
    ...
}

class customCollection
{
    protected $items = [];  
    public function add($item) {
        $this->items[$item->getIdentifier()] = $item;
    }
    public function remove($item) {
        unset($this->items[$item->getIdentifier()]);
    }
    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->items;
    }
}
```

I could use object aggregation and pass an array of collection items to the constructor and use this as the initial collection items of this custom collection object but this could be a problem if the add method possibly modify multiple object properties. So how would you solve this task or is just a integration test fine for this? Thanks for feedback!

Comment: doing unit testing assumes intensive usage of mocks for dependecies substitution. i don't see this particular case to be any special for not to follow this proposition. just couple of lines and your test is safe (and your production code, too).

Answer (score 2):

If `Item` is simple enough, don't bother with complications and integration test is fine. Write few tests to test `Item` first and then test `customCollection`. If `Item` tests run fine and `customCollection` test fails, the bug is most likely in the collection.

If `Item` is very complex, let it implement an interface required by the collection and then you can stub `Item` with a trivial implementation of this interface. Then test `Item` and the trivial implementation separately, and then the collection with trivial implementation and later also with the `Item` implementation. (But I doubt it is worth the effort.)

The point of separating unit tests and integration tests is in easy localization of where the bug is. But it is fine if you achieve the same with well structured integration tests only.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. My concern refers to the remove method of the collection. I have to call the add function to populate the items property and if there is some failure in this method, the remove test would also fail although it works perfectly fine and the failure occurs only because of a mistake in the implementation of the add method.

Comment: I would test both methods together. First `add` some items, then check whether they are properly inserted, then `remove` them and check again. I don't see anything wrong with this and I don't see any other option here. It is not a good idea to make tests too large and too complex, but this is not the case -- you have two complementary actions, it makes sense to test them together.